# svelte js: rendering mathml via mathjax

Tags: mathjax, svelte

I have a sveltejs SPA where I load some mathml content and display it via mathjax.
Here is the relevant code

```
async function hashChange() {
  await renderContent();
  console.log("content *NOT* rendered, but it should!");
  MathJax.typeset();
  console.log("content is rendered only now");
}

onMount(() => {
  hashChange();
});
```

The problem is that the page is rendered only after MathJax.typeset(), while I would expect a first render of the raw mml after renderContent() and then a refresh with the typesetted mml after MathJax.typeset().

I have tried to use MathJax.typesetPromise(), but the result is the same.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The code you've posted is not enough in itself to trigger a rerender in Svelte. What you want to achieve would typically be done by changing the value of `let` variables at strategic points in time. But answering that would need to know more about your markup and what happens in your other functions. Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I indeed have an assignment inside fetchMMlContent and infact this trigger a render. Problem is that the rendering happens only after the call to MathJax.typeset() has returned. I would expect an immediate render after fetchMMlContent and then an update with the mathml after MathJax.typeset(), like what happens if you load the same content in the browser w/o using svelte.

Comment: With this code, you should have an initial empty render, before your fetchMMlContent resolves, so there's probably something else going on. Maybe in your markup.